# \IfStrEqCase redefines #1

Tags: strings, xstring, parameters, arguments

What is the meaning of `#1`, `#2`, etc in the optional parameter of `\IfStrEqCase`?

[image]

This required me to use a `##1` instead of `#1` within `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` which I was not expecting.

I would have expected `#1` to be undefined as it is outside of `\IfStrEqCase`. I have added a more elaborate test whose output is

[image]

Seems a little bizarre to me that I can use `#1` when invoking a macro? Are there other macros that I can invoke which have similar behavior? And the behavior seems different if I use `\IfStrEqCase` within a macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
    \IfStrEqCase{5}{
        {1}{}%
        {2}{}%
    }[{
        param 1 = #1,\par
        param 2 = #2,
    }]
\end{document}
```

### Code: More Elaborate Test Case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\PrintFirstParamaterIfNotOneOrTwo}[1]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{
        {1}{x}%
        {2}{y}%
    }[{
        param 1 = #1,\par
    }]
}

\begin{document}
    \IfStrEqCase{xxxx}{
        {1}{x}%
        {2}{y}%
    }[{
        param 1 = #1,\par
    }]

    \PrintFirstParamaterIfNotOneOrTwo{xxxx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as the xstring macros are not expandable and make many internal definitions the treatment of `#` is well defined but essentially arbitrary and just reflects the internal implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change to

```
    {1}{x}%
    {2}{y}%
```

you will see #1 is 2 and #2 is y, you say that isn't what you expected, but you didn't say what you did expect?

Comment: I would expect it to trigger an error just as it would outside of `\IfStrEqCase`.  What was not obvious was why `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,...,\MaxCount}{ p#1 }` with the `pgfplots` package loaded was starting at `p3` instead of `p1` until I change it to `p##1`.

Comment: Added a more elaborate test case that hopefully shows why I think this is confusing. Perhaps there is something really basic that I am misunderstanding.